# AWS and Flask file upload/donwload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've hosted my Flask web application using Zappa(Which uses AWS and S3 at the back). My application involves uploading and downloading of files. When I try to do either of the actions, I get the following error.

***IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system***

Why is S3 blocking uploads/downloads and how do I change it to read-write?

You can access the hosted application  [here](https://k8m00unpc6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/)

```
@app.route('/paper_upload',methods=['POST','GET'])
def paper_upload(): # Journal Upload
    if  request.method == 'POST' and 'file' in request.files:
        filename = files.save(request.files['file'])

        doc = Journal(title=request.form['Title'],user_email=session['email'],
                    domain=request.form['domain'],status="Submission received",filename=filename,date=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        doc.save()
        flash('Journal Submitted')
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

@app.route('/download/<filename>',methods=['POST','GET'])
def download(filename):
    return send_file(safe_join('app.config['UPLOADED_FILES_DEST']',filename),as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: @kichik included corresponding flask code.

Comment: This code has nothing about S3. It just tries to save the file to the local file system, which in your case is on Lambda because you use Zappa. You should add code to write the file to S3.

Comment: I tried adding os.chdir('/tmp') and the uploading worked. The downloading didn't work when I did the same. It seems that S3 saves the files to tmp.

Comment: Each Lambda execution can have its own `/tmp` folder. You don't have a server with a persistent `/tmp` folder. It's a Serverless architecture.

Comment: What would be the best alternative to implement a download?

Comment: Don't use Serverless. Start with something simpler. Or actually [upload to S3](http://zabana.me/notes/upload-files-amazon-s3-flask.html).

Comment: Oh right! Should've used boto3. Thanks!